# How can we use axes option of ts.plot for matrix in R?

Tags: r

I would like to plot multiple time series by using `ts.plot` **nothing else**. I tried, however, I faced error message and I could not find suitable answer for it.

Here is a test code.

```
a <- 1:10
b <- a + 5
c <- b + 5
d <- c + 5
ts.plot(cbind(a,b,c,d), axes=F)
```

The result is :

```
Error in .cbind.ts(list(...), .makeNamesTs(...), dframe = dframe, 
union = TRUE) :no time series supplied
```

We are not going to see this error if we do not use `axes` option.
I'd appreciate if someone can give me a helping advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the axes you need to do it this way:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- a + 5
c <- b + 5
d <- c + 5
ts.plot(cbind(a,b,c,d), gpars=list(xaxt='n', yaxt='n'))
```

[image]

If you see the ts.plot documentation you will see that it looks like this:

```
ts.plot(..., gpars = list())
```

This means that any graphical parameter needs to go in the list of gpars otherwise it will be considered a time series object and ts.plot will try to plot it as such.

By adding an axes=F argument, `ts.plot` just tries to plot it as a time series object (which obviously is not), so it fails with the error.

Comment: > By adding an axes=F argument r just tries to plot an axes=F time series which obviously is not a time series object. -> I understand. Thank you for your answer!